# php selected option Undefined index

Tags: php

I get `Undefined index` on the 6th line (`if` condition). What is the reason?

```
<select name="day" id="day">
<?php
for($i=01; $i<=31; $i++)
{
    echo "<option value='$i'";
    if ($_POST['day'] == $i){ echo "selected";}
    echo">$i</option>";
}
 ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is crystal clear: the key `day` does not  (always) exist in `$_POST`.

So you have to check if it does first:

```
if (isset($_POST['day']) && ($_POST['day']==$i)) { 
    echo "selected";
}
```

Comment: this line ImageFile give me the same error what is the correct syntax to write? if($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']!="" && isset($_POST['L1']))

Comment: @faedmohammed Well, what about `if(isset($_FILES['ImageFile']) && ($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']!="") && isset($_POST['L1']))`?

Comment: ok works fine solved! thk.

Comment: @faedmohammed It is important that you understand _why_ this works and what the actual cause of those warnings is... Just copying some suggestion does not really help you to learn...

Comment: same error on username and after using your method result Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)  on code: if($_POST['UserName']!="" && $_POST['Password1']!="" && $_POST['Password2']!="" && $_POST['Email']!="" && $_POST['Name'] !="" && $_POST['Country'] !="" && $_POST['State'] !="" && $_POST['City'] !=""&& $_POST['ZipCode'] !="" && $_POST['Adress'] !=""  && $_POST['idnumber']!=""&& $_POST['phone']!="" && $_FILES['ActImage']['tmp_name']!="" && $_FILES['RImage']['tmp_name']!="" && $_POST['checkbox']!="")

Comment: This is what I feared: you did _not_ bother to understand what has been shown to you, you just try to copy it blindly. I suggest you start learning and understanding. Start by reading the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: solved: if(isset($_POST['UserName']) && ($_FILES['UserName']!="") && $_POST['Password1']!="" && $_

Answer (score 0):

That's beacuse `$_POST['day']` is not set.

Comment: how to se it? i dont know

Comment: By sendind a POST request with a day field, with AJAX, with a form... You can also use $_GET['day'] that it will be set by the URL. Example: example.com/form.php?day=2